# Submitting Form Data in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a webpage that involves a contact page. This contact page (once submitted the form), will use contact.php to submit the form into a database. I then have a "admin" page which allows me to see the submitted forms.

However, I am having a problem with the submission of the form. Once I click submit, it takes me back to the same page but with no new record in the database. I will write the relevant code below. That may help.

Here is my github for this project too: https://github.com/jacklythgoee/CodeHeads

Contact.php-

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
$errors = [];

require_once __DIR__ . '/../survey.php';
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $errors = validateFormData(
        $_POST['contact_name'] ?? '',
        $_POST['contact_email'] ?? '',
        $_POST['contact_subject'] ?? '',
        $_POST['contact_message'] ?? ''

    );

    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        // No errors, create the record.
        try {
            $id = createForm(
                $db,
                $_POST['contact_name'],
                $_POST['contact_email'],
                $_POST['contact_subject'],
                $_POST['contact_message']
            );
            $_SESSION['flash'] = [
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => sprintf('Record with id %d has been created successfully', $id),
                'id' => $id,
            ];
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            $_SESSION['flash'] = [
                'type' => 'danger',
                'message' => 'Could not create a new record'
            ];
        }

        header("Location:contact.php");
        exit;
    }
}

$data = [
    'title' => 'Contact us',
    'extra_css2' => [
        'contact.css',
        'mainframe.css',
        
    ],
    'action' => 'contact.php'
];
require_once __DIR__ . '../../templates/contact.phtml';
```

Survey.php -

```
function validateFormData(
    string $contact_name,
    string $contact_email,
    string $contact_subject,
    string $contact_message
): array {
    $errors = [];


    return $errors;
}


function createForm(
    PDO $db,
    string $contact_name,
    string $contact_email,
    string $contact_subject,
    string $contact_message

): int {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `contact` (`contact_name`, `contact_email`, `contact_subject`, ``, `created_at`) 
                                  VALUES (:contact_name, :contact_email, :contact_subject, :contact_message, :created_at)';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->execute([
           ':contact_name' => $contact_name,
           ':contact_email' => $contact_email,
           ':contact_subject' => $contact_subject,
           ':contact_message' => $contact_message,
           'created_at' => (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       ]);
        $db->commit();
        return (int)$db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// This file will boostrap the application.
// Because I did not use an autoloader for this example, I will initialize the application here.
// This file needs to be included in each entrypoint php file.
//
//

session_start();

// Load the application settings
require_once __DIR__ . '/settings.php';

// Initiate the database connection.
require_once __DIR__ .'/database.php';
```

Contact.phtml

```
<form action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">

   <?php if (isset($data['record']['id'])): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $data['record']['id'] ?>"/>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if (isset($data['currentPage'])): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?= $data['currentPage'] ?>"/>
   <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>

    <input type="email" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required>

    <input type="text" name="contact_subject" id="contact_subject" placeholder="Enter Your Subject" required>

    <textarea rows="8" name="contact_message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

   <button type="submit" class="hero-btn red-btn">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `currentPage` defined?

Comment: Inside a public php file inside $data

Answer (score 0):

In `if (isset($_POST['page'])) {` you check for POST parameter named `page`, but in your html form there is not any input by name `page`.

You can add a hidden input named `page` to `Contact.phtml` like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="contact">
```

Comment: This didnt work...